# partitioning a key search

Tags: c, arrays, string, search

I need to iterate through a series of 8 character string from aaaaaaaa to zzzzzzzz, similar to a brute force attack. Right now, I have the following horrible mess of nested loops to do it:

```
int start = 97;
int range = 25;
int a;
for(a = start; a <= start+range; a++) { //1
    strb[0] = a;
    for(b = start; b <= start+range; b++) { //2
        strb[1] = b;
    for(c = start; c <= start+range; c++) { //3
            strb[2] = c;
            for(d = start; d <= start+range; d++) { //4
                strb[3] = d;
                for(e = start; e <= start+range; e++) { //5
                    strb[4] = e;
                    for(f = start; f <= start+range; f++) { //6
                        strb[5] = f;
                        for(g = start; g <= start+range; g++) { //7
                            strb[6] = g;
                            for(h = start; h <= start+range; h++) { //8
                                strb[7] = h;
                                check(str);
                            tot++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although this code works well for the whole set of search space, I also need to partition the search in smaller pieces, in order to carry out a concurrent search operation with multiple threads. E.g. I want to be able to search just for the 3rd 1/25 of the search space, or say, the 2nd 1/15.

I need to somehow unfold this nested loops into one to achieve that, but I couldn't figure out how. I'm using C. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid "horrible mess of nested loops" learn about recursive program.

Comment: To avoid recursive programming, learn how to do it into a loop. It's easier to understand a for loop than a recursive, and easier on resources use.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is just an iterator that works on alphabetic order, it's something like:

```
calculateNext(char strb[8]){
int i;
  for(i=7; i<=0; i++){
    if(strb[i]<'z'){
      strb[i]++;
      break;
    } else {
       strb[i]='a';
       strb[i-1]++;
    }
  }
}
```

i'm not sure this works totally, but the overall idea is that, when the last element is z, then sum on the next one, if not, then sum on it and iterate.